# How can I include a RowVerson column in a table valued parameter when calling a stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net, table-valued-parameters

If I have a SQLDataRecord that includes a RowVersion column as shown in the code below.   I always get a SQL Server Error 8052

> The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC)
>   protocol stream is incorrect. Table-valued parameter %d ("%.*ls"), row
>   %I64d, column %d: Data type 0x%02X (user-defined table type) timestamp
>   column is required to be default.

whether I set the RowVersion value to null or a value.

I want to be able to send a RowVersion value for existing records and null for new records from ADO.NET to a stored procedure such that I can then using optomistic concurrency checking when merging records.

How can this be done?

```
namespace MyApplication.DataAccess
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Linq;
    using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

    public interface IRowVersionRecord
    {
        Byte[] RowVersionValue { get; set; }
        Int32? Somevalue { get; set; }
    }

    public class RowVersionRecordBase : IRowVersionRecord
    {
        public Byte[] RowVersionValue { get; set; }
        public Int32? Somevalue { get; set; }

        public static IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord> CreateSqlDataRecordEnumerable(IEnumerable<IRowVersionRecord> dataTransferObjects)
        {
            var sqlMetaData = new SqlMetaData[]
            { new SqlMetaData("RowVersionValue", SqlDbType.Timestamp),
                new SqlMetaData("somevalue", SqlDbType.Int)
            };
            var record = new SqlDataRecord(sqlMetaData);
            foreach (var dto in dataTransferObjects)
            {
                record.SetValue(0, dto.RowVersionValue);
                record.SetValue(1, dto.Somevalue);
                yield return record;
            }
        }
    }

    public partial class RowVersionRecord : RowVersionRecordBase
    {
    }
}

namespace MyApplication.DataAccess
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;

    public abstract class RowVersionDAOBase : DAO
    {
        public virtual void Upsert(IEnumerable<RowVersionRecord> values)
        {
            using (var connection = Connection)
            {
                using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.CommandText = "RowVersion_Upsert";
                    ((SqlCommand)command).Parameters.Add("@values", SqlDbType.Structured).Value =
                        (object)RowVersionRecordBase.CreateSqlDataRecordEnumerable(values) ?? (object)DBNull.Value;                    
                    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection | CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
                    {
                        while (reader.NextResult())
                        {
                            ///.....
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public partial class RowVersionDAO : RowVersionDAOBase
    {
    }
}

//Test code snip
[TestMethod]
public void RowVersionTVPTest()
{
    RowVersionRecord record = new RowVersionRecord();
    record.Somevalue = 1;
    List<RowVersionRecord> records = new List<RowVersionRecord>()
    {
        record
    };
    using (RowVersionDAO dao = new RowVersionDAO())
    {
        dao.Upsert(records);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can never control the contents of a `rowversion` column - but you've indicated that you want to provide specific values for existing rows.

That would indicate that you should use [`binary(8)` or `varbinary(8)`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx) (depending on not-NULL/NULL, respectively) as the data type for that column in the TVP instead.

Comment: What I'm not getting here is that I can have a RowVersion as a normal parameter to a stored procedure and I can pass a value into the procedure as a byte[8].   However, if I declare a TVP column as RowVersion, I am not able to specify the value as byte[8].  I have not found any documentation stating that the RowVersion type can be set when used with a parameter declaration but not for a TVP column.  If that is the case, why can a user defined table type have a RowVersion column if it can never be set? Or can it and how?

Comment: @RichardCollette - it's following the rules for tables, rather than the rules for parameters, as should not be surprising - e.g. you cannot have *two* rowversion columns in a user defined table type, but you can create two parameters of type rowversion and pass those to a stored procedure. And if you have a local variable of the UDTT, any `INSERT` or `UPDATE` into that table will follow the usual, expected rules.

Comment: @Damien_TheUnbeliever I get what you're saying about it behaving consistently but it doesn't behave consistently.  On the server you can select into a UDTT and the existing row version values will be copied into the UDTT.  But from ADO.NET, I have no way to insert rows that have an existing ROWVERSION value.  Not only that, but I can't specify that the TVP row I am  passing to the server have a default value in the RowVersion column either.   If the TVP is a UDTT that contains a RowVersion column, then the TVP cannot be used from ADO.NET (I have yet to see an example of it.)