# C#, SQL Server: Pass a UDT with a Timestamp column into a stored procedure from C#

Tags: c#, t-sql

Using SQL Server 2019 I have a stored procedure where I pass in values via a user defined table type.  One of the columns is a timestamp table type which is used for row version and data concurrency control.

From C# I load a datatable to pass in as a parameter for the UDT, however, I get an error saying I cannot write to a timestamp.

How can I pass the value of the timestamp into the stored procedure via a UDT where it can be used to compare with a timestamp value in the database?

Here’s my UDT:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[tvp_Eav_Value] AS TABLE(
[EavVl_Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[EavVl_EavEnt_Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[EavVl_EavAt_Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[EavVl_Value] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[EavVl_LastModifiedUserId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
[EavVl_Stamp] [timestamp] NULL
)
```

And here’s the datatable I’m passing in:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("EavVl_Id", typeof(Guid));
dt.Columns.Add("EavVl_EavEnt_Id", typeof(Guid));
dt.Columns.Add("EavVl_EavAt_Id", typeof(Guid));
dt.Columns.Add("EavVl_Value", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("EavVl_LastModifiedUserId", typeof(Guid));
dt.Columns.Add("EavVl_Stamp", typeof(byte[]));
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using a `DateTime` instead of a `byte[]`?  How would you expect a `byte[]` to get converted to a time stamp

Comment: you don't assign the value of a `timestamp`; it's controlled by SQL Server.

Comment: You can't. Heed the error: a `timestamp` (better named `rowversion`) column cannot be set client-side through any means. You should not have a column like that in a table type as you can't meaningfully use it; you can use a `BINARY(8)` and convert it to `ROWVERSION` as needed for comparisons.

Comment: @Flydog57 `timestamp` is a binary value; assigning a `datetime` to it makes no sense.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does a timestamp in T-Sql mean in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334777/what-does-a-timestamp-in-t-sql-mean-in-c)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I include a RowVerson column in a table valued parameter when calling a stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19729157/how-can-i-include-a-rowverson-column-in-a-table-valued-parameter-when-calling-a) @devlincarnate I think this one is more directly related

Comment: Thanks All.  The comment from @Jeroen is the answer I needed.  I just needed a way to move the timestamp value via the table type.